Defining rigorously a sequence such that $y\in f(x_0,\cdots,x_n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
Let $A,Y$ be two sets, $\sigma \in A$ and $y\in Y$. Define $A^{<\mathbb{N}}:=\cup _{n\in\mathbb{N}}A^n$ with $A^0:=\emptyset $ and $A^n$ being the $n$-fold cartesian product of $A$. Suppose that $f:A^{<\mathbb{N}}\to \mathcal{P}(Y)$ is a function, $y\in f(\sigma )$ and, given any $(a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1})\in A^n$, if $y\in f(a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1})$, then there's an $a\in A$ such that $y\in f(a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1},a)$.
My question is: how can I prove rigorously that exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $A$ (that is, a function $\mathbb{N}\to A,\,n\mapsto x_n$) such that $x_0=\sigma$ and $y\in f(x_0,\cdots,x_n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Generally to define such sequence we use words such as "we'll define the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ inductively". I want to know how to make this notion precise.
I tried to use the axiom of dependent choice in order to construct that sequence, but I failed to make any progress.
Maybe it's possible to define that sequence using the Principle of Recursive Definition for Well-Ordered Sets, however I haven't studied this principle so I'd like other approach if it's possible.

Wait, wouldn't any $f$ that just doesn't map to any set containing $y$ give us a counterextable? Or is $y$ not fixed?

@kabelabel I corrected some mistakes in the question!

$A^0$ is not empty - it has a unique element, namely the empty sequence $\varepsilon$. Realizing this simplifies your setup, because you don't need to start with $\sigma\in A$. Instead, you can just assume $y\in f(\varepsilon)$.

The simplest way to do this is using "strong" or "complete" recursion. I'll quote the version from Moschovakis's Notes on set theory, where it appears as Exercise 5.27 on p. 70. An equivalent version appears (with a proof given) as Theorem 3.3.5 on p. 50 of Introduction to Set Theory by Hrabacek and Jech.

For each $h\colon E^*\to E$, there exists exactly one function $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to E$ which satisfies the identity $f(n) = h(\overline{f}(n))$.

Note that $E^*$ is Moschovakis's notation for $E^{<\mathbb{N}}$, and for $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to E$, $\overline{f}(n)$ is Moschovakis's notation for $(f(0),f(1),\dots,f(n-1))\in E^n$.
Now to apply this theorem to your situation, take $E = A$. Let $c$ be a choice function for the set of non-empty subsets of $A$. For $\overline{a} = (a_0,\dots,a_{n-1})\in A^n$, let $X_{\overline{a}} = \{a\in A\mid y\in f(a_0,\dots,a_{n-1},a)\}$. Then define
$$h(\overline{a}) = \begin{cases} \sigma & \overline{a} = \varepsilon \text{ or } X_\overline{a} = \varnothing\\
c(X_{\overline{a}}) & \text{otherwise},\end{cases}$$
where $\varepsilon$ is the empty sequence in $A^0$.
By the strong/complete recursion theorem, we obtain a function $g\colon \mathbb{N}\to A$ such that $g(n) = h(\overline{g}(n))$. Writing $x_n$ for $g(n)$, we have $x_n = h(x_0,\dots,x_{n-1})$ for all $n$.
Note that $x_0 = h(\varepsilon) = \sigma$. It remains to prove by induction on $n$ that $y\in f(x_0,\dots,x_n)$.
When $n = 0$, this is by hypothesis: $y\in f(\sigma)$.
Now assume $y\in f(x_0,\dots,x_{n-1})$. Then writing $\overline{x} = (x_0,\dots,x_{n-1})$, by hypothesis $X_{\overline{x}}\neq \varnothing$. So $x_n = h(x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}) = c(X_{\overline{x}})$, so $x_n\in X_{\overline{x}}$. That is, $y\in f(x_0,\dots,x_n)$.

Thank you very much!
